# Git: How to undo unstaged changes in a certain folder

Tags: git

I made many changes which were `not staged`, and I want to undo changes in a certain folder, how can I achieve this?

I knew that use `git stash` will undo all changes, so how can I achieve my above goal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a certain file: `git checkout -- filename`
a certain path: `git checkout -- path`
all changes: `git checkout -- .`